# Limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac {1^{a+1}+2^{a+1}+\cdots+n^{a+1}}{n.(1^{a }+2^{a }+\cdots+n^{a })}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

The value of $$\lim_{n=\infty} \dfrac {1^{a+1}+2^{a+1}+\cdots+n^{a+1}}{n.(1^{a }+2^{a }+\cdots+n^{a })}  $$

**Attempt:** $S = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0} ^\infty \dfrac {k^{a+1}} {n.( 1^{a }+2^{a }+\cdots+ n^{a} )}$

I am trying to use the integral as a limit of sum but the denominator is preventing me from applying.

Could anyone please give me a direction to move on.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In $S$, you have $n$ "double defined" (once as the limit variable and once as the index of the summation).

Comment: Hi, @MathMan, can you please tell me what the source of this question is ?? A very similar question came recently in my test, it will be really helpful if you could please tell me from where this problem was taken ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit can be interpreted as the ratio of two Riemann sums. First of all we have that

$$I_k = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^k = \int_0^1 x^k dx = \frac{1}{k+1}$$

which gives $$S = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{a+1}}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{a}} = \frac{I_{a+1}}{I_a} = \frac{a+1}{a+2}$$

where in the second step above I have used the fact that if $a_n$ and $b_n$ converges then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n}{\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n}$.

Comment: Great Answer :) Thank you. I have a question though please. Shouldn't $I_{a+1}$ be equal to $\dfrac {1}{a+2}?$

Comment: @Wanderer You are absolutely right, I have corrected it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $1^a+2^a+\cdots+n^a\sim {n^{a+1}\over a+1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint !:)

Comment: If $\alpha=-1$ then $\sim\log\,n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: instead of Riemann sums you could try use immediately [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), and a little investigation for some special values of $\alpha$.